# How to get chat dialog of each user by admin login?

Tags: quickblox

My application has a functionality of pulling all chat records from quickblox,But i am not able to get all chat dialog from admin login.Please confirm if i will need each user login details for getting dialog id.If yes,then where can i get the access credential.

Answer (score 0):

We confirm that you will need user login details for getting dialog ID. 
You will not be able to get access to all the users' credentials due to security reasons, as it will be a privacy breach.